# Track clicks on different iframes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to track clicks on iframes on my site. So far this code is working and is triggered every time a click happens on an iframe.

```
var monitor = setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
        alert('click on iframe');
        clearInterval(monitor);
    }
}, 500);
```

Now what I would like to do is to trigger different actions based on which iframe is clicked. Since I don't have control over classes or id's that the iframes might have I need to rely on the parent div's which are under my control, so I'm trying something like this which is currently not working.

```
var monitor = setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
        if ($elem.parents('.ad_left').length) {
            alert('this is an ad left iframe');
        }
        else if ($elem.parents('#youtube').length) {
            alert('this is a youtube iframe');
        }
        else () {
            alert('click on different iframe');
        }
        clearInterval(monitor);
}, 500);
```

Is this not possible or amd I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, this is the code I used to check fi any ancestor of the iframe contains a particular class and performing different actions based on that:

```
var monitor = setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
        if (elem.closest('.class_one') !== null) {
            alert('this iframe has a parent with class class_one');
        }
        else if (elem.closest('.class_two') !== null) {
            alert('this iframe has a parent with class class_two');
        }   
        else if (elem.closest('.class_three') !== null) {
            alert('this iframe has a parent with class class_three');
        }     
        clearInterval(monitor);
    }
}, 500);
```